# SQL query to show time trend of a SCD Type 2 dimension table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, etl

Table given below:

```
pk,EmployeeNo,Building,ValidFrom,ValidTo. 
1, 1, a, 2000-01-01, 2008-06-01
2, 1, b, 2008-06-01, 2010-06-01
3, 1, c, 2010-06-01, 2011-08-01
4, 2, a, 2000-01-01, 2008-06-01
5, 2, b, 2008-06-01, 2010-06-01
6, 2, c, 2010-06-01, 2011-08-01
```

I'm a relatively novice SQL developer and I'm using MS SQL Server. I would like to devise a SQL query that can take the table above - built using type 2 slowly changing dimensions (with a validfrom date and validto date) -- and produce a table of daily trend customer count over time.


 Output below:

```
Date, Employee Count
1/1/2000, 2
1/2/2000, 2
```

Comment: The question is not clear. The sample data is about Employees, yet you want an output for customer count. Also it is not clear what the output should be for other dates like what is should show for 1/3/2000

Comment: @K4M, appreciate the note.  I edited the question above.  From the table, you should see that the employee count for 1/3/2000 should be 2.

Comment: Hi - I have a couple of questions to help me understand what you are trying to achieve:

1) Are you trying to produce daily counts within an arbitrary date range or for all days between the MIN ValidFrom and MAX ValidTo in your dataset? If not, what are the dates in your sample output?

2) As your ValidFrom and ValidTo values overlap, is a record valid when it is <= ValidTo or when it is < ValidTo (or some other logic)?

Comment: @NickW, I'm trying to produce daily counts for all days between the min validfrom and max validto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a cumulative sum -- after unpivoting the data:

```
with d as (
      select validfrom as dte, 1 as inc
      from t
      union all
      select validto, -1
      from t
     )
select dte, sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte)
from d
group by dte
order by dte;
```

Note:  This assumes that the `validto` date is not included.  If you want it included, then add "1" to it.

EDIT:

If you only need the results for those two dates, then use:

```
select v.dte,
       (select count(*) 
        from t
        where t.validfrom <= v.dte and t.validto >= t.validto
       ) as cnt
from (values ('2020-01-01'), ('2020-01-02')) v(dte);
```

Comment: This answer is not considering SDC Type 2 nature of the table. Depending on which columns are SDC Type 2, the query should account for them.

Comment: For other readers, this doesn't produce the desired output, there is no row coming out for '1/2/2000' . But I liked the logic in general

Comment: @K4M . . . I added a solution to get the two specific dates that you want.

Comment: But that would be hard-coding and doesn't scale. But not your fault, the question is not clear with intended outputs.

Comment: BTW, I got impressed with your effort in SQL questions here. As I start answering a question, I see that you already sent an answer :) I ordered one of your books the other day. Thanks for your help to the community @gordon-linoff

Comment: @K4M, provided more context above.  For this example, was considering the "Building" column to be the SCD Type 2.

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL seems to work. I have assumed that the Employee is valid up to, but not on, the ValidTo date to avoid double counting on these dates when the ValidFrom and ValidTo overlap; you'll need to amend the INNER JOIN logic if this assumption is incorrect.

```
    --Get the min and max dates in the employee table
DECLARE @todate date, @fromdate date
SELECT @fromdate= min(ValidFrom) from [POC].[dbo].[EmployeeSCD2];
SELECT @todate= max(validto) from [POC].[dbo].[EmployeeSCD2];

-- Generate a list of all the dates between the two dates
WITH calendar (FromDate) AS (
    SELECT @fromdate AS FromDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, FromDate)
    FROM Calendar
    WHERE FromDate < @todate
)
-- Join the list of dates to the employee table - gives a record per date per employee active on that date
SELECT CAL.FromDate, COUNT(EMP.EMPLOYEENO) 'Employee Count' 
FROM CALENDAR CAL
INNER JOIN [POC].[dbo].[EmployeeSCD2] EMP ON CAL.FromDate >= EMP.ValidFrom AND CAL.FromDate < EMP.ValidTo
group by cal.FromDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- Without this parameter the recursion stops after 100 loops
;
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy ways is to build a date table and then count how many employee (or customer) were in that particular date.

```
;with t as (   -- this is your table/Dimension
    select pk,EmployeeNo,Building,ValidFrom,ValidTo 
    from (values (1, 1, 'a', '2000-01-01', '2008-06-01'),
                 (2, 1, 'b', '2008-06-01', '2010-06-01'),
                 (3, 1, 'c', '2010-06-01', '2011-08-01'),
                 (4, 2, 'a', '2000-01-01', '2008-06-01'),
                 (5, 2, 'b', '2008-06-01', '2010-06-01'),
                 (6, 2, 'c', '2010-06-01', '2011-08-01')
        )t (pk,EmployeeNo,Building,ValidFrom,ValidTo)
)
, dates as ( -- this is a recursive query, building a date table from 2000-01-01 up to today
    select convert(date, '2000-01-01') as d
    union all
    select DATEADD(d,1,d) 
    from dates 
    where d < getdate()-1
)
select d.d, count(1) as [Employe count]  
from dates d
inner join t on d.d between t.ValidFrom and t.ValidTo -- will join only valid employee
group by d.d 
option (maxrecursion 0)  -- since our dates table recurse over more than 100 times and the dataset is fairly small, you need this option
```